# .getJSON response not happening

Tags: c#, jquery, api

Can someone please put another set of eyes oh this? I am trying to validate that a blob image exists prior to displaying. This could take 1-4 seconds. 
my JS looks like this:

```
   var url = '/api/blob/ValidateBlobExists?id=' + blobImage;
        $.getJSON(url,
            function(json) {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .done(function () {
                console.log("second success");
                 exists = data;
                if (exists) {
                    console.log("exists'");
                $('#imgPhotograph').hide().attr('src', blobImage).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#imgPhotograph').attr('src', '../Images/NoPhotoFound.jpg');
            }
        });
```

the api looks like this.. please don't judge.. its vb because it has to be.

```
   Public Function ValidateBlobExists(id As String) As JsonResult(Of Boolean)
    dim result = CDNHelper.BlobExists(id) 'this could take ~5 seconds
    Return Json(Of Boolean)(result)
End Function
```

the underlying method looks like this:

```
  public static bool BlobExists(string filename)
    {
        try
            {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                do
                {
                    if (client.AssertBlobExists(filename).Result) // <-- this is a wrapper to query the azure blob
                     return true;

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); //no reason to hammer the service

                } while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 8000);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

the thing is in my console output I can't even get to the "success". It seem the getJson() is just not willing to wait for the 8 seconds to elapse before continuing. Any thoughts are appreciated .

Comment: Add a `fail()` callback to see if the request is failing for some reason. Check the network tab of the dev tools to see if the request is actually going through

Comment: ^^^ and verify that the response on the request is actually valid json

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my API response signature was not decorated as Async. Even though I was calling .result it was getting messed up. The solution for me was to modify my code as below

```
 Public Async Function ValidateBlobExists(id As String) As Task(Of JsonResult(Of Boolean))
         result = await CDNHelper.BlobExists(id, "ioc")
         return result
End function
```

and

```
public static async Task<bool> BlobExists()
{
return client postasync wrapper
}
```